# Symfony: Build doctrine schema out of sql azure db

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, odbc, azure-sql-database

My DSN String looks like this:

```
  dsn:      odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=myserver.database.windows.net;Database=mydb;
  username: myusername@myserver
  password: mypwd
```

When I run the symfony task:

```
symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

It seems be a successfull connection, but it breaks with the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 2812 
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure
'sp_primary_keys_rowset'. (SQLExecute[2812] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254). 
Failing Query: "EXEC sp_primary_keys_rowset @table_name = Appointment"
```

Does anybody know what's the problem here? I could not find any useful information about there error codes.

I use symfony 1.4.10, PHP 5.3, SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Does the stored procedure `sp_primary_keys_rowset` exist in your database?

Comment: No I can't find it. I found a MSDN page about API System Stored Procedures http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx

Comment: Wenn I look into a normal SQL Server DB I have these required system stored procedures but not in the SQL Azure DB.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

In symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Import/Mssql.php listTableColumns($table) I had to change

```
$sql = 'EXEC sp_primary_keys_rowset @table_name = ' . $this->conn->quoteIdentifier($table, true);
```

to

```
$sql = 'EXEC sp_pkeys @table_name = ' . $this->conn->quoteIdentifier($table, true);
```